# Trailing Slashes in URL

Tags: php, phalcon

So, I've been trying to find stuff online about it, but no where in the documentation is there anything regarding trailing slashes in URLs. Here's my problem.

I want all URLs to end with a slash, and, potentially, redirect them if they don't. Now, my code works with and without a slash, but I get two different results when I `var_dump( $this->dispatcher->getParams() );`

Here's my code for the route

```
<?php
    // for brevities sake, it's only the route

    $router->add('/:controller/:action/:id/', array(
        'controller'    => 1,
        'action'        => 2,
        'id'            => 3
    ));
```

Now, that trailing slash I have there doesn't really do anything, so I just left it. For the URL **/user/view/13/**, here's the var_dump for `$this->dispatcher->getParams()`:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(2) "13"
  [1]=>
  string(0) ""
}
```

If I run the URL **/user/view/13** (without the trailing slash), here's the **var_dump** for
 `$this->dispatcher->getParams()`:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(2) "13"
}
```

Essentially, is there a way I can get phalcon to end at the trailing slash, so that I get the same results? Or will I potentially have to write a custom Routing class? Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For versions <= 0.7.0, you can add an optional / to the regular expression in each route:

```
$router->add('/:controller/:action/:id[/]{0,1}', array(
    'controller'    => 1,
    'action'        => 2,
    'id'            => 3
));
```

Note: :id is not a valid placeholder in Mvc\Router instead of it you can use :int

Starting from 0.8.0, you can enable the automatic correction of trailing slashes:

```
$router->removeExtraSlashes(true);
```